# Display an alert with message according to the radio button chose

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, radio-button, alert

I'm creating a role playing game questionnaire for a Pathfinder campaign. I thought to create a it of sorts to give various bonuses to the characters playing based on how they answer the questions listed.  I plan to adjust the content below, I just need to know how to write the code displaying input radio button values selected for each question.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>

function myFunction()
{
var queone = document.getElementById("qone").value;
var quetwo = document.getElementById("qtwo").value;
var quethr = document.getElementById("qthr").value;

if (queone == 1) { 
alert("You are now +2 Acrobatics");
}
else if (queone == 2) {
alert("You are now +2 to Bluff");
}
else if (queone == 3) {
alert("You are now +2 Diplomacy");
}

if (quetwo == 1) { 
alert("You are now +2 Acrobatics");
}
else if (quetwo == 2) {
alert("You are now +2 to Bluff");
}
else if (quetwo == 3) {
alert("You are now +2 Diplomacy");
}

if (quethr == 1) { 
alert("You are now +2 Acrobatics");
}
else if (quethr == 2) {
alert("You are now +2 to Bluff");
}
else if (quethr == 3) {
alert("You are now +2 Diplomacy");
}
}
</script>

<div>



<h2 align="center">Fantasy Survey</h2>
<p>Do you love fantasy games?</p></br></br>
<input id="qone" name="radio1" value="1" checked="" type="radio">Yes</br></br>
<input id="qone" name="radio1" value="2" type="radio">Meh</br></br>
<input id="qone" name="radio1" value="3" type="radio">No</br></br>
<p>Have you ever considered playing pen and paper games?</p></br></br>
<input id="qtwo" name="radio2" value="1" checked="" type="radio"> Yes</br></br>
<input id="qtwo" name="radio2" value="2" type="radio"> Meh</br></br>
<input id="qtwo" name="radio2" value="3" type="radio"> No</br></br>
<p>Do you like Pathfinder?</p></br></br>
<input id="qthr" name="radio3" value="1" checked="" type="radio"> Yes</br></br>
<input id="qthr" name="radio3" value="2" type="radio"> Meh</br></br>
<input id="qthr" name="radio3" value="3" type="radio"> No</br></br>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit" />


</div>
</html>
```

I'm looking to display an alert with a bonus for the characters depending on what selection they make via the radio button values.  I feel like I'm close, but I don't know how to only alert values related to the specific radio button(s) selected.  If you have a better way, I'm happy to hear it, but I would like to have it done similarly to what I've posted above.

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for. You want one alert that accounts for all three options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all ids have to be unique.So that needs to be corrected.Change those and try jquery selectors.If you are new to this script language i would recommend you to try [this](http://try.jquery.com/)

Here is the working code

```
var queone =   $( "input[type='radio'][name='radio1']" ).val();
var quetwo =   $( "input[type='radio'][name='radio2']" ).val();
var quethree = $( "input[type='radio'][name='radio3']" ).val();

if (queone == 1) { 
  alert("You are now +2 Acrobatics");
}
else if (queone == 2) {
  alert("You are now +2 to Bluff");
}
else if (queone == 3) {
 alert("You are now +2 Diplomacy");
}

if (quetwo == 1) { 
  alert("You are now +2 Acrobatics");
 }
else if (quetwo == 2) {
  alert("You are now +2 to Bluff");
 }
 else if (quetwo == 3) {
   alert("You are now +2 Diplomacy");
 }

 if (quethree == 1) { 
   alert("You are now +2 Acrobatics");
  }
else if (quethree == 2) {
  alert("You are now +2 to Bluff");
 }
else if (quethree == 3) {
   alert("You are now +2 Diplomacy");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are giving different elements the same `id` value. The `id` attribute should be unique for all elements.
In your case, `getElementById` will always return the first item it comes across, not necessarily the selected one.

What you can do is use the `querySelector` function, which should work from IE8 upward, and in all other browsers.

`document.querySelector("input[name=radio1]:checked")` should return you the correct items.

You can always take a look at `jQuery` as a helpful library, but it's not *needed* for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>

function myFunction()
{
    for(k=1; k<=3; k++)
        checkVal(document.getElementsByName("radio"+k))     

}

function checkVal(selector){
for (var i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {       
        if (selector[i].checked) {
            switch (selector[i].value){
                case '1' :
                    alert("You are now +2 Acrobatics")
                    break;
                case '2' :
                    alert("You are now +2 to Bluff")
                    break;
                case '3' :
                    alert("You are now +2 Diplomacy")
                    break;  

                }

            break;  

        }
    }
}
</script>

<div>
  <h2 align="center">Fantasy Survey</h2>
  <p>Do you love fantasy games?</p></br></br>
  <input name="radio1" value="1" checked="" type="radio">Yes</br></br>
  <input name="radio1" value="2" type="radio">Meh</br></br>
  <input name="radio1" value="3" type="radio">No</br></br>
  <p>Have you ever considered playing pen and paper games?</p></br></br>
  <input name="radio2" value="1" checked="" type="radio">Yes</br></br>
  <input name="radio2" value="2" type="radio">Meh</br></br>
  <input name="radio2" value="3" type="radio">No</br></br>
  <p>Do you like Pathfinder?</p></br></br>
  <input name="radio3" value="1" checked="" type="radio">Yes</br></br>
  <input name="radio3" value="2" type="radio">Meh</br></br>
  <input name="radio3" value="3" type="radio">No</br></br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit" />
</div>
</html>
```